# Adding a button in a Grouped tableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a `Grouped Table View` like the [one shown in this image](http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/Picture-32.png). What i need to do is to add a button between the 2 Groups, is that possible ? If so how could i code it ?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is possible, you shall implement in your view controller a table delegate method, i.e.:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
   if (section == 0) {
        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        [button setTitle:@"Hello" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        // other initialization here...
        return button;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom header view for your table and place a button here, making your custom view to be used only for 2 and later sections.